# Qt Convert Negative Hex String to Signed Integer

Tags: c++, qt, signed, hex

I am reading the registers of an i2c device and the range of the return value is -32768 to 32768, signed integers. Below is an example:

```
# i2cget -y 3 0x0b 0x0a w
0xfec7
```

In Qt, I get this value ( 0xfec7 ) and want to display it in a QLabel as a signed integer. The variable stringListSplit[0] is a QString with the value '0xfec7'.

```
// Now update the label
int milAmps = stringListSplit[0].toInt(0,16); // tried qint32
qDebug() << milAmps;
```

The problem is no matter what I try I always get unsigned integers, so for this example I am getting 65223 which exceeds the maximum return value specified. I need to convert the hex value to a signed integer, so I need to treat the hex value as being expressed with 2s complement. I am not seeing a simple method in the QString documentation. How can I achieve this in Qt?

NOTE:

QString::toShort returns 0:

```
// Now update the label
short milAmps = stringListSplit[0].toShort(0,16);
qDebug() << "My new result: " << milAmps;
```

For an input of stringListSplit[0] equal to '0xfebe', I get an output of -322, using the C-style casting answered by Keith like so:

```
// Now update the label
int milAmps = stringListSplit[0].toInt(0,16);
qDebug() << "My new result: " << (int16_t)milAmps;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your result to a signed 16-bit integer.

```
qDebug() << (int16_t)milAmps;
```

Comment: never ever use C-style casting :)

Comment: @fasked: Yeah, old habits die hard...  Now get off my lawn!

Comment: well thanks this seems to work but is there any reason this would be unsafe / frowned upon??

Comment: In C++ you should do `static_cast<int16_t>(milAmps)` instead.  No danger in this case, but using the C++ casts makes it less likely you'll accidentally cast a string to an integer or some other bogus cast.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert this string to 16-bit integer. It's most likely you can use `QString::toShort` method.

```
short milAmps = stringListSplit[0].toShort(0,16); 
qDebug() << milAmps;
```

Comment: `toShort` method can return `0` if error happened. Are you sure that `stringListSplit[0]` is correct string?

Comment: Probably complaining about the input being out of range.  You'll need to parse as integer and cast it down.

Comment: Yep, If I use Keith's suggestion for C-style casting I get -318 for 0xfec2. But If I use the toShort() method it return 0.